# Szemerédi Regularity Lemma - finding regular pairs of "large" size

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, additive-combinatorics

The [Szemerédi Regularity Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma) states that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a constant $M$ (dependent only on $\epsilon$) such that every graph $G$ has a $\epsilon$-regular partition of its vertex set into at most $M$ parts.

If one follows the proof (or other discussion therein) closely, $M$ is actually an astronomically large quantity - basically, $M$ is of the order of $2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}$ where the height is polynomial in $1/\epsilon$. Thus, by the time one reaches an $\epsilon$-regular partition guaranteed by the lemma, the part sizes might be some vanishingly small fraction each.

> Can I do better if I want to find just one $\epsilon$-regular pair of
> subsets (not necessarily disjoint or distinct)? Specifically, is it
> possible to find some $C>0$ such that for every sufficiently small
> $\epsilon$ (say for all $\epsilon < 1/4$), every graph contains some $\epsilon$-regular pair of
> vertex subsets (not necessarily disjoint/distinct) such that each is of size at least
> $(\frac{1}{2})^{(1/\epsilon)^C}|V(G)|$?

I tried the following approach (which is based on one of the common ways of proving the Szemerédi Regularity Lemma): Let the graph $G$ be given. Start off with $X_0=Y_0=V(G)$. If $(X_0,Y_0)$ is $\epsilon$-regular, we are good for this graph $G$. Otherwise, find $A_0\subset X_0, B_0 \subset Y_0$ which causes the regularity to be violated. Let $X_1$ be the larger of $X_0, X_0-A_0$ and $Y_1$ be the larger of $Y_0, Y_0-B_0$. Then each of $X_1, Y_1$ is of size $\ge \frac{1}{2}|V(G)|$. Once again check if $(X_1, Y_1)$ is $\epsilon$-regular and repeat the above argument.

The key then is to show that this process always terminates after a number of steps that is bounded above by polynomial in $1/\epsilon$. However, this is where I am unable to proceed. I tried to track the [energy between the two partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma#Proof) at each step but the increase in energy is getting smaller geometrically (specifically, the energy between the partitions is guaranteed to increase by $\epsilon^4 (1/4)^k$ at step $k$). Thus there is no reason why the process must terminate.

**Another idea I have**: By considering $G$ or its complement, we can reduce the problem to a bipartite graph with $\ge n(n-1)/8$ edges between the "left" and "right" parts, and the goal is to find a subset on the left and a subset on the right so that these two form a regular pair.